Selenium python change default directory for download without opening windows popup
I would like to change the default download directory using Selenium. I also want to avoid the Windows dialog box from opening to select the name because I can't interact with Selenium. If I leave the default directory, it downloads the file directly, but if I try to change it, it opens the Windows dialog box. Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

For Firefox, here's how you can configure an automatic download to a location of your choice:
from selenium import webdriver

download_location = "C:\\temp"

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("browser.download.panel.shown", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_location)
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.animateNotifications", False)
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference(
    "browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
    (
        "application/pdf, application/zip, application/octet-stream, "
        "text/csv, text/xml, application/xml, text/plain, "
        "text/octet-stream, application/x-gzip, application/x-tar "
        "application/"
        "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
    ),
)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

# ...

driver.quit()


...and in Chrome you'd use something like: chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",
{"download.default_directory":  path-to-download-dir})

Ok thank you, It works. It was also important to use the absolute path because iwas using the relative path and it didn't work
